# Difference between kilogram-force and kilogram

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, units, unit-conversion

I know that a 1 kilogram-force is the force of 1 kilogram acted upon by 1 standard unit of gravity (9.80665 m/s^2).

However, in torque descriptions I find that some use $kgf*cm$  while  others use $kg*cm$ or $oz*in$. Is converting from one to the other unit as simple as dividing $kgf*cm$ by the acceleration of gravity to get $kg*cm$?

Answer (score 1):

The [kilogram-force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilogram-force) is *not* a standard unity:

*The kilogram-force (kgf or kgF), or kilopond (kp, from Latin pondus meaning weight), is a gravitational metric unit of force. It is equal to the magnitude of the force exerted by one kilogram of mass in a 9.80665 m/s2 gravitational field (standard gravity, a conventional value approximating the average magnitude of gravity on Earth).[1] Therefore one kilogram-force is by definition equal to 9.80665 N.[2][3] Similarly, a gram-force is 9.80665 mN, and a milligram-force is 9.80665 µN. One kilogram-force is approximately 2.204622 pounds-force.
Kilogram-force is a non-standard unit and does not comply with the SI Metric System.*

but it has nevertheless the units of Force.

A [torque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque) is instead defined

> generally, the torque on a particle (which has the position r in some
>   reference frame) can defined as the cross product:
>
> $\boldsymbol{\tau} = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F}$, where $r$ is the
>   particle's position vector relative to the fulcrum, and $F$ is the force
>   acting on the particle.

Therefore whenever you find torque descriptions they are usingthe units of Force and distance

Comment: Additionally, if you use kilogram-force here you get told off by the pedants who pretend not to understand what it means

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. How do I convert $kgf*cm$ to $kg*cm$?

Comment: @Cerin, they are different concepts and therefore have different units. You do not convert one ito another: can you convert velocity into acceleration or into momentum or into Kinetic energy? you cannot,in the same way you cannot convert force into torque, you use the right unit in the appropriate context. Hope it's clear, now